# can i optimize this function even more

Tags: python, optimization, graph, dynamic-programming

well , I'm looking for ways to optimize a function that i wrote as an answer to this problem in python:

"Given a square matrix of integers with each row containing the time it takes to get to the start, first person, second person, ..., last person, and the exit in that order. The order of the rows follows the same pattern (start, each person, exit).Picking the persons up is instantaneous,it's possible to  revisit different spots , and moving to the exit doesn't mean you have to immediately leave - it's possible to move to and from the exit to pick up additional persons if time permits.Some paths add time back to the clock. Adding time to the clock will delay the closing of the exit doors, and if the time goes back up to 0 or a positive number after the doors have already closed, it triggers the exit to reopen. Therefore, it might be possible to walk in a circle and keep gaining time: that is, each time a path is traversed, the same amount of time is used or added.

The Goal is to write a function to calculate the most persons one can pick up and which persons they are, while still escaping through the exit before the door closes for good.The function should return return the indexes of the saved persons in sorted order.
"

The function that i wrote is :

```
def answer(times,time_limit):   
    mindic=min(min(times))
    n=len(times)
    def find_path(times, start, end,time, path=[]):
        if start != 0 and start != end :
            if start-1 in path:
                pass
            else:
                path = path + [start-1]
        if start == end and time-min(times[start][0:len(times[start])-1]) < mindic:
            return path
        best=None
        for i in range(n):
            if time-times[start][i] >= mindic and times[start][i] != 0 :
                newpath = find_path(times, i, end,time-times[start][i], path)
                if newpath != None :   
                    if not best or len(newpath) > len(best):
                        best=newpath
        return best
    res=find_path(times,0,n-1,time_limit)
    return res
```

calling the function will be something like this :

```
answer([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]],3)
```

and the answer for the above example is :

```
[0, 1]
```

it will only be able to save the persons with index 0 and index 1.

running the function with '%% timeit 10' gives the following :

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 180 µs per loop
```

is there any way to reduce the time ?

**EDIT**: Thanks @quantummind , got it from 221 µs to 180 µs.

**EDIT2**: @user2357112: i beleive i have fixed the problem ? Now it will not reject the paths that visit the same spot twice .

Comment: From a quick look, your function doesn't even seem to be correct. It does `if len(path) != len(set(path)): return`, rejecting all paths that visit the same spot twice, even though it may be necessary to revisit locations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in CodeReview, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't try to understand your code fully, but it might help a little if you change these lines

```
if start != 0 and start != end :
    path = path + [start-1]
if len(path) != len(set(path)):
    return
```

to:

```
if start != 0 and start != end :
    if start-1 in path:
        return
    path = path + [start-1]
```